# Rails lib/module with 'class Class' and custom attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I want to make my own attr_accessor like this:

```
  class Class
    def attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback(*args, &block)
      raise 'Callback block is required' unless block
      args.each do |arg|
        attr_name = arg.to_s
        define_method(attr_name) do
           self.instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}")
        end
        define_method("#{attr_name}=") do |argument|
          old_value = self.instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}")
          if argument != old_value
            self.instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}", argument)
            self.instance_exec(attr_name, argument, old_value, &block)
          end
        end   
      end
    end
  end
```

It works if I put this definition in `config/enviroment.rb` before app initialization.

```
class MyCLass < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback :some_attr do |attr_name, value, old_value|
  end
```

But I think it should be inside lib/ folder. If I put this

```
module ModelHelpers
  class Class
    def attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback(*args, &block)
      raise 'Callback block is required' unless block
      args.each do |arg|
        attr_name = arg.to_s
        define_method(attr_name) do
           self.instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}")
        end
        define_method("#{attr_name}=") do |argument|
          old_value = self.instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}")
          if argument != old_value
            self.instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}", argument)
            self.instance_exec(attr_name, argument, old_value, &block)
          end
        end   
      end
    end
  end
end
```

to `lib/model_helpers.rb` and this

```
require 'model_helpers'
class MyCLass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModelHelpers
  attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback :some_attr do |attr_name, value, old_value|
end
```

to my_class.rb then I get an error: `undefined method attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define your method attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback directly in ModelHelpers, without class Class. And use extend keyword instead include inside class defenition. Like this:

```
module ModelHelpers
  def attr_accessor_with_onchange_callback(*args, &block)
...

require 'model_helpers'
class MyCLass < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ModelHelpers
```

Here is my example:

```
module ModelHelpers
    def my_method
        puts 'ModelHelpers::my_method called.'
        puts "self is #{self}"
    end
end

class MyCLass 
  extend ModelHelpers
  my_method
end
```

And output is:

```
> ruby custom_method_inside_class.rb
ModelHelpers::my_method called.
self is MyCLass
```

Comment: Nope, same error `undefined method`. As I know it has to be inside `Class` since it's a new class method for all classes